# How to retrieve a key from a Json String Node JS using a var for the key name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Here is how one conventionally gets a value from a json object:

```
var random_json_string = "{ "name": "YOLO"}";
var value = JSON.parse(random_json_string);

var key = value.name; // key is now "YOLO"
```

But I want to do this :

```
var keyTitle = "name";
var random_json_string = "{ "name": "YOLO"}";
    var value = JSON.parse(random_json_string);

    var key = value.keyTitle; // I cannot do this because the code tries to search the json object for a child with the name ketTitle instead of searching for the child with the name : "name"
```

Notice on the last line I want to search for the key with the name that is defined by the var keyTitle.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), like so:

```js
var keyTitle = "name";
var random_json_string = `{ "name": "YOLO"}`;
var value = JSON.parse(random_json_string);

var key = value[keyTitle];

console.log(key)
```

Comment: How about the case where suppose var keyTitle = "name.lastname", and my json object has a key that has a key. I tried to do var key = value[keyTitle] for this case but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: `console.log()` the `keyTitle` and see what value it's getting.